# Vue Google Chrome Password Autofill disable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, password-protection

I'm trying to disable reminder of my password input field at my login screen. Here is my input field:

```
<r-input
        type="text"
        id="login_username"
        width="95%"
        v-model="formJson.username"
        labelColor="white"
        @keyup.enter="handleLogin"
      ></r-input>
```

I tried `autocomplete=off`, but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Actually now ı can disable autofill my username input area with autocomplete="new-password" but when my input area type="password" it doesnt work as well, ı need disable autofill password input area as well

Comment: I think you need to read the whole page, as there is a lot of discussion about how to disable autofill in chrome, and a link to a chrome issue that details reasons why people need to disable autofill, so that the issue can properly be resolved. That is to say, there is no guaranteed way to disable autofill at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

try this:
[vue-disable-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-disable-autocomplete)

**How to use**

```js
import DisableAutocomplete from 'vue-disable-autocomplete';

Vue.use(DisableAutocomplete);
```

**HTML attribute**

```html
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: i tried but not working

Answer (score 3):

You only need to put in the autocomplete parameter: nope

```
<input
  type="text"
  v-model="name"
  autocomplete="nope"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to a similar question here on stackoverflow
[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Since **Sept 2020:** `autocomplete="chrome-off"` disables Chrome autofill.

Answer (score 1):

I know the subject is old, but it seems that with each update of Chrome, the problem comes back.
I tried in several ways, including `autocomplete="nope"` and `this.$refs.inputHoweverName.$el.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'nope');`

Recently in Chrome version 87.0.4280.88, the only way I could, without having to install any plugin, using native javascript, was to create a dynamic id:

**markup example**

`<v-text-field :id="dynamicID()" ... </v-text-field>`

**method example**

`dynamicID() { return 'dynamicID-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * Date.now().toString()); },`

I do not know if it is the most elegant and efficient way, but for me it solved and that in many is enough.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to install

**npm install --save vue-disable-autocomplete**

import this one

**import DisableAutocomplete from '@aacassandra/vue-disable-autocomplete';
Vue.use(DisableAutocomplete);**

for input...

for form...

Comment: this is setting inputs to readonly ... what good is that?

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete="off" will be ignored by most browsers. You can pass a string there to help the browser find the correct autocomplete.
Example: autocomplete="email"
To switch it off, pass something that the browser will not understand.
Example: autocomplete="shut-up-google" will switch the autocomplete off.